# SUM the values that appear multiple times into one row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet:

[image]

I am trying to write code to be able to combine multiple values into one row, I need to sum the values from columns, B, C and D.

My aim is to be able to press a button and I have all of my duplicate values removed, but before this, the numerical values in the adjacent columns are summed into the single version.

So far I have removed the duplicates from the column:

```
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
With Columns("A:A")
.Replace What:="mobile", Replacement:=""
End With
```

Comment: hi, do you really need vba for this since you can use a pivot table to achieve same result.

Comment: Hi, I did already consider this but I would like to be able to clean the data this way.

Comment: I was wondering if my answer below worked? Since I am also still in learning stage, I would like to revise it if it is not working. Thank you in advance for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous code should do your job. It may need a fine tuning but idea would work. Do not forget to make proper addressing of worksheets for your ranges. I did not do it. This will work on the active sheet currently.

Update: Updated with worksheet addresses.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim S_Value As String

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2
While i <= LastRow

    S_Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    j = i + 1
        While j <= LastRow
            If ws.Range("A" & j).Value = S_Value Then
                ws.Range("B" & i).Value = ws.Range("B" & i).Value + ws.Range("B" & j).Value
                ws.Range("C" & i).Value = ws.Range("C" & i).Value + ws.Range("C" & j).Value
                ws.Range("D" & i).Value = ws.Range("D" & i).Value + ws.Range("D" & j).Value
                ws.Rows(j & ":" & j).EntireRow.Delete
                LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                j = j - 1
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Wend
i = i + 1
Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
Sub SumCount()
    Dim s, c, sm
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Rws, 4))
    s = InputBox("What Number to Find?")
    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, s)
    sm = s * c
    MsgBox sm

End Sub
```